# A Preposterous Puzzle

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

## The Preposterous Puzzle

[image]

In text form:

```
ONGOKEAU
TTFDNQAN
ITHZTEEC
HLTIEZST
RUINKTLU
EHSLSIEH
TUSNOTPO
EUIOOSGD
```

The word *preposterous* traces to the roots *prae* (before) and *posterous* (subsequent).

The modern usage of this word conveys an absurdity, but it was originally meant more precisely to convey something that is out of order... taking something that should be subsequent and putting it before.  (Maybe you can suggest a more modern way of conveying this idea, but let's just go with this for now).

It is in this sense that this puzzle is preposterous, because the answer tells you how to find the solution to this puzzle.

Comment: FYI, lateral thinking only applies if the intended solution bypasses logic.

Comment: @thecoder16 According to the tag description, I'm pretty sure it applies to this puzzle.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain there isn't a typo on the 6th line? I'd really like an S as the fourth letter there.

Comment: @Bass No typo; the S's on the sixth line are precisely where they need to be.

Comment: @HWalters "involving ideas that may not be obtainable only using logic" this is the important part of the description, not just the creative part.

Comment: Yeah, the tag description could use some work, lateral-thinking solutions are usually outside-the-box type solutions that use information that was not given in the puzzle. In general, puzzles of the enigmatic variety are best enjoyed with no extra tags, since they can give away unintended clues. Oh, and thanks for the excellent puzzle!

Comment: I'm glad you enjoyed it.  Thanks for the tag cleanup.

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but do you make puzzles professionally? The overall quality of this puzzle is lightyears above the average "first question" on this site, which makes me wonder if you have made more of them, and if you have, have you published them somewhere?

Comment: @Bass No; if I made a living this way I'd be starving... just had a nice idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The letter distribution looks similar to English, so it's probably a transposition cipher. The grid is a 8x8 square, which sounds familiar. Let's see if we can't find a famous order in that same famous order..

> [image]
>
>  Well, "Knight's tour" wasn't there. Picking letters like a chess knight moves seems to work though, `knight` can be found, as can `queen`

I'll post this as partial while I try to work out the rest.

UPDATE: Got it. The message is:

> **Using the queen's knight, take a closed tour to find the solution to this puzzle .**

Following the message's instructions:

> [image]

Comment: Oh, there's more? Yay!

Comment: @Bass "the queen's knight" suggests starting at B1/B8 (if this were a chessboard)

Comment: So I should start the sentence at "Nd the solution using"? :-) I'll update the answer in a minute. (Yoda might think about viewing this board from black's perspective: a closed tour... , take.)

Comment: @Bass No, if you start from B1 doesn't it say "Using the queen's knight, take a closed tour to find the solution"?

Comment: @thecoder16, in Internet parlance, the colon-dash-closing paren combination indicates well-meaning, jocular intent. :-)

Comment: I thought that was the opening paren for your afterthought oops :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74360/discussion-between-thecoder16-and-bass).

Comment: Please ignore that, it was a button I'd never seen before somehow and I clicked it for the sake of clicking it